# How to handle multiple forms on a single page using Suave.Experimental

Tags: f#, suave

I have to create simple page with multiple form. I decide to use Suave.Experimental for this purpose. When I click on `submit` button on the second form, I get the following error

> Missing form field 'Second'

WebPart

```
let webpart =
    choose [
        GET >=> OK page
        POST >=> bindToForm firstForm firstHandle
        POST >=> bindToForm secondForm secondHandle
    ]
```

**Is it possible to have multiple form with Suave.Experimental?**

If so - what I was missing here?

If not - what will be appropriate approach to do it?

The minimal example is below:

```
open Suave.Form
open Suave.Html

type FirstForm = { First : string }
type SecondForm = { Second : decimal }

let firstForm : Form<FirstForm> = 
    Form ([ TextProp ((fun f -> <@ f.First @>), [ ])],[])

let secondForm : Form<SecondForm> = 
    Form ([ DecimalProp ((fun f -> <@ f.Second @>), [])], [])

type Field<'a> = {
    Label : string
    Html : Form<'a> -> Suave.Html.Node
}

type Fieldset<'a> = {
    Legend : string
    Fields : Field<'a> list
}

type FormLayout<'a> = {
    Fieldsets : Fieldset<'a> list
    SubmitText : string
    Form : Form<'a>
}

let form x = tag "form" ["method", "POST"] x
let submitInput value = input ["type", "submit"; "value", value]

let renderForm (layout : FormLayout<_>) =    
    form [
        for set in layout.Fieldsets -> 
            tag "fieldset" [] [
                yield tag "legend" [] [Text set.Legend]

                for field in set.Fields do
                    yield div ["class", "editor-label"] [
                        Text field.Label
                    ]
                    yield div ["class", "editor-field"] [
                        field.Html layout.Form
                    ]
            ]

        yield submitInput layout.SubmitText
    ]

open Suave
open Suave.Filters
open Suave.Operators
open Suave.Successful
open Suave.Web

open Suave.Model.Binding
open Suave.RequestErrors

let bindToForm form handler = 
    bindReq (bindForm form) handler BAD_REQUEST

let firstHandle first = 
    printfn "first = %A" first
    Redirection.FOUND "/"

let secondHandle second = 
    printfn "second = %A" second
    Redirection.FOUND "/"

let page = 
    html [] [
        head [] [ ]
        body [] [
            div [][
                renderForm
                    { Form = firstForm
                      Fieldsets = 
                        [ { Legend = "1"
                            Fields = 
                              [ { Label = "Text"
                                  Html = Form.input (fun f -> <@ f.First @>) []  }
                                  ] }]
                      SubmitText = "Submit" }

                renderForm
                    { Form = secondForm
                      Fieldsets = 
                        [ { Legend = "2"
                            Fields = 
                              [ { Label = "Decimal"
                                  Html = Form.input (fun f -> <@ f.Second @>) [] }
                                  ] }]
                      SubmitText = "Submit" }
            ]
        ]
    ]
    |> htmlToString

let webpart =
    choose [
        GET >=> OK page
        POST >=> bindToForm firstForm firstHandle
        POST >=> bindToForm secondForm secondHandle
    ]

startWebServer defaultConfig webpart
```

Answer (score 0):

You are routing the same route 'POST /' to both of your form handlers. You should have only one route for each one otherwise only one of those are ever executed.

You could set different form action for each of your forms and create paths for those accordingly.

I quickly made these changes to your code and it should work now:

```
open Suave.Form
open Suave.Html

type FirstForm = { First : string }
type SecondForm = { Second : decimal }

let firstForm : Form<FirstForm> = 
    Form ([ TextProp ((fun f -> <@ f.First @>), [ ])],[])

let secondForm : Form<SecondForm> = 
    Form ([ DecimalProp ((fun f -> <@ f.Second @>), [])], [])

type Field<'a> = {
    Label : string
    Html : Form<'a> -> Suave.Html.Node
}

type Fieldset<'a> = {
    Legend : string
    Fields : Field<'a> list
}

type FormLayout<'a> = {
    Fieldsets : Fieldset<'a> list
    SubmitText : string
    Form : Form<'a>
}

let form action x = tag "form" ["method", "POST"; "action", action] x
let submitInput value = input ["type", "submit"; "value", value]

let renderForm action (layout : FormLayout<_>) =    
    form action [
        for set in layout.Fieldsets -> 
            tag "fieldset" [] [
                yield tag "legend" [] [Text set.Legend]

                for field in set.Fields do
                    yield div ["class", "editor-label"] [
                        Text field.Label
                    ]
                    yield div ["class", "editor-field"] [
                        field.Html layout.Form
                    ]
            ]

        yield submitInput layout.SubmitText
    ]

open Suave
open Suave.Filters
open Suave.Operators
open Suave.Successful
open Suave.Web

open Suave.Model.Binding
open Suave.RequestErrors

let bindToForm form handler = 
    bindReq (bindForm form) handler BAD_REQUEST

let firstHandle first = 
    printfn "first = %A" first
    Redirection.FOUND "/"

let secondHandle second = 
    printfn "second = %A" second
    Redirection.FOUND "/"

let page = 
    html [] [
        head [] [ ]
        body [] [
            div [][
                renderForm "first"
                    { Form = firstForm
                      Fieldsets = 
                        [ { Legend = "1"
                            Fields = 
                              [ { Label = "Text"
                                  Html = Form.input (fun f -> <@ f.First @>) []  }
                                  ] }]
                      SubmitText = "Submit" }

                renderForm "second"
                    { Form = secondForm
                      Fieldsets = 
                        [ { Legend = "2"
                            Fields = 
                              [ { Label = "Decimal"
                                  Html = Form.input (fun f -> <@ f.Second @>) [] }
                                  ] }]
                      SubmitText = "Submit" }
            ]
        ]
    ]
    |> htmlToString

let webpart =
    choose [
        GET >=> OK page
        POST >=> choose 
            [ path "/first" >=> (bindToForm firstForm firstHandle)
              path "/second" >=> (bindToForm secondForm secondHandle) ]
    ]

startWebServer defaultConfig webpart
```